# Before Send android studio .apk to my client what should I do?

Tags: android

I want to send my android studio (apk) file to my client to check.But I have a doubt that he may be upload it to play store and won't give my payment.How I am add password to (apk) file?Or how I secure it?

Comment: Send him the debug apk, it won't get upload.

Comment: yes please send him debug apk

Answer (score 1):

You can send debug apk through firebase App Distribution feature
For more details please visit official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution